# SP Online Powershell web.RequestAccessEmail is not returning any value

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I am creating a script to check if the site has Request Access Enabled. this is a snippet of my script:

```
$ctx = GetClientContext $url $username $password;
$web = $ctx.Web
$ctx.Load($web)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

foreach($w in $web.Webs)
{

      Write-Host $w.Title " - " $w.Url " Access Request Email - " $w.RequestAccessEmail  -ForegroundColor Gray

}
```

it is not returning any value even though it is enabled, however, it does print if i set a value to it which i dont want to do. why is it not returning any value? Also, i am not finding RequestAccessEnabled command.

Comment: after setting the value, did you check it in the site, can you see the updated value?

Comment: Hi @KarthikJaganathan , yes the site has a value but the script is giving me blank values. but when i try to set a value for the RequestAccessEmail, it works. not sure what im missing.

Answer (score 1):

Had only SP on-premise to try how the script would work (ofc by adjusting it to server-hosted at first), and the email was returned successfully when it was set. This might be a current issue with SP Online, in which case you should target the question directly to Microsoft.

Also, `RequestAccessEnabled` is there, and it would return `true`, if request for access is enabled. (see: [SPWeb.RequestAccessEnabled property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.requestaccessenabled%28v=office.15%29.aspx).)

Comment: Hi @moe, i tried to debug the code but then there is no command for RequestAccessEnabled in the intellisense.

Comment: do you have to set a value before it can be returned by the script?

Comment: @PageF.P.T no, I was able to just do the `Write-Host` without setting anything.